# customize next, previous button in jquery cycle

Tags: javascript

I want the text in next and previous button in my jquery cycle should show the title from next & previous slide respectively. How can I do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

cycle is pretty well documented - view the source of this page:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html